# What are the occasions/days to keep a fast?

Tags: sawm

I know there are several days aside from Ramadhan, during which Islam advises to observe fasting. I would like know what those days are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are the occasions on which is suggested to fast:

- Mondays and Thursdays.  [Source](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:745)
- Fasting the 13, 14 and 15 of every month.  [Source](http://sunnah.com/nasai/22/331)
- The tenth of Muharram. [Source](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/106)
- the of Dhul-Hijja (The day of Arafah).  [Source](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/260)
- Six days of Shawwal.  [Source](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/264)
- The ninth day of Muharram.  [Source](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/263)
- The Fasting of Dawood (Peace be upon Him). [Source](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/92)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hadith in Sahih Muslim that is at least one answer to your question:

> He was then asked about fasting for a day and breaking on the other, whereupon he said: That is the fasting of my brother David (peace be upon him). He was then asked about fasting on Monday, whereupon he said: It was the day on which I was born. on which I was commissioned with prophethood or revelation was sent to me, (and he further) said: Three days' fasting every month and of the whole of Ramadan every year is a perpetual fast. He was asked about fasting on the day of 'Arafa (9th of Dhu'I-Hijja), whereupon he said: It expiates the sins of the preceding year and the coming year. He was asked about fasting on the day of 'Ashura (10th of Muharram), whereupon be said: It expiates the sins of the preceding year.

From http://sunnah.com/muslim/14#253 (what is quoted above is a part of the full hadith - click on the link for the full hadith)

To summarize fasts from this hadith:

- Fasting every other day is the best (the fast of Prophet Dawud)
- Fasting on Mondays
- Fasting thrice a month (13-15: the "White Days")
- Fasting on Arafah day (9 Dhul Hijjah)
- Fasting on the 10th of Muharram

Comment: note that the three days of each month are days 13-14-15 of each arabic month

Comment: @Zeina - jazakillahu khair for pointing that out. I know there are other ahadith that point that out, feel free to post as another, more detailed answer :)